# Is there a way to import the div class="inner-wrap" element in the html generated by mdl-js using bs4?

Tags: html

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77
    Safari/537.36'}  
    url  = 'https://school.programmers.co.kr/learn/challenges? 
    order=recent&levels=3&languages=python3'
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        
    if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    main = soup.select("div", {"class": "inner-wrap"})
    print(main)
```

I want to access the inner-wrap element of the photo using bs4!!

[image]